# Should I book overtime for an optional after-hours meeting in a bar?

Tags: meetings, after-hours

I was invited to an optional meeting by one of my managers to discuss our new website with one of his marketing friends. The meeting is taking place after our normal work hours. It is also at a bar where I am sure that drinks will ensue. Seeing as this is not a mandatory work meeting, do I stay clocked in for the time spent there actually talking about the website?

Comment: We can only speculate. The only sure way to know is ask your manager.

Comment: @LaconicDroid , that would be like saying "Should my company randomly give me $72?"  answer - "who knows, better ask someone".  Self-evidently, charge for every minute, every second, worked.

Comment: @Fattie - And your comment is like saying "every employment contract for consultants, managers and employees in every country in the world is exactly the same".

Comment: Are you salaried I would assume so from the nature of the meeting

Comment: I am an hourly wage employee.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normally, you'd book this as overtime if you were actually working.

If it's more of a casual thing and your attendance isn't strictly necessary, then treat it as a social thing, assume that your manager will pay for drinks/food and leave whenever you want to.

Don't forget that this is a networking opportunity.  Sometimes the value of getting yourself known is better than getting the overtime payment.

Comment: I mostly agree with this, though I wouldn't assume the boss will pay for food and drinks unless they said they would. I think the manager *should* cover the meal, but that doesn't necessarily mean they will. If the boss hasn't given any indication the meal is on them, it will look bad if you leave without at least offering to pay your share.